# WPF validation error causes double to be converted to int

Tags: wpf, textbox, validationrules

I implemented custom validation rules to use with `TextBoxes` in my WPF project. I have the following problem:

If, for example, I have a textbox for entering double values, after validation errors (e.g. for typing "30.0" I have to get a validation error when text is "30.") the validation / binding mechanism converts double representation of integer numbers ("30.0") to int representation ("30").
If I keep the validation rules but return always ValidationResult.ValidResult or remove the validation rules, the value does not change and remains "30.0".

How can I fix it / workaround it?

Comment: Please post some code (binding, property, and validation).  What happens when the textbox is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control when the binding fires. If it happens on each keystroke, then you'll have a problem with the invalid intermediate `30.` case, as you describe.

You might like to look at adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` to your Binding.

There's some more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356.aspx